# Tkinter installation for python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, installation

I was unable to install `tkinter` for Python 3.10 in the conda environment for Python 3.10 on a Windows machine. Here is the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Tkinter should be included in python, no need to separately install it. Do you have a reason to believe tkinter is not installed already?

Comment: Are you able to `import tkinter` without errors? If not, you may need to reinstall Python.

Comment: `tkinter` is installed after installing `anaconda3`, so why do you need to install `tkinter`?

Answer (score -1):

I installed `tkinter` using `pip3 install tk` (typed at the conda command prompt).

Output :

```
Collecting tk
  Using cached tk-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
Installing collected packages: tk
Successfully installed tk-0.1.0
```

Comment: Note that the `tk` module installed by `pip` is not `tkinter` module.  `tkinter` cannot be installed via `pip`.

Comment: just try this :   python -m tkinter

Comment: It means that you have `tkinter` already installed.  Check the description in `pypi.org` for `tk`, it is something like `tensorkit`.